# Not broken by player loot table?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I have a loot table that makes it so logs only drop when mined with an axe; That part was easy. But I noticed it did not drop to creeper explosions/tnt due to failing the match tool check, which obviously I would like to fix if possible.

I am now having difficulties making it also drop from explosions and the below should work but does not seem to be.

```
  "type": "minecraft:block",
  "pools": [
    {
      "rolls": 1,
      "bonus_rolls": 0,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "minecraft:alternatives",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "minecraft:item",
              "name": "minecraft:acacia_log",
              "conditions": [
                {
                  "condition": "minecraft:match_tool",
                  "predicate": {
                    "items": [
                      "minecraft:wooden_axe",
                      "minecraft:stone_axe",
                      "minecraft:iron_axe",
                      "minecraft:golden_axe",
                      "minecraft:diamond_axe",
                      "minecraft:netherite_axe"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "minecraft:item",
              "name": "minecraft:acacia_log",
              "conditions": [
                {
                  "condition": "minecraft:survives_explosion"
                },
                {
                  "condition": "minecraft:inverted",
                  "term": {
                    "condition": "minecraft:entity_properties",
                    "entity": "this",
                    "predicate": {
                      "type": "minecraft:player"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is it not dropping from tnt? Is that somehow passing the not-player check? I tried it with creepers too since maybe tnt lit by players still counts, and same thing.

Comment: From a JSON perspective, I would think you should be specifying all of the conditions within the first `conditions` array rather than as new objects because you already specified `minecraft:acacia_log` in the `children` array. But, I don't know what Minecraft expects.

Comment: To my undertsanding, "alternatives" causes minecraft to iterate through until it finds one that it matches, then it exits and does not continue, the behavior that I need. That is why each drop has conditions individually.

Comment: @Aceplante right, but it's worth trying, no?

Comment: Do you want the block to drop upon _any_ explosion, regardless of the power or radius? You have programmed the `minecraft:survives_explosion` condition, which is programmed to fail if the explosion is too large or too close, which will stop the item from dropping at all.

Comment: I guess if thats the only way, but Id prefer if regular explosion mechanics applied. Like I said, I want wood to only be mineable (by the player) with an axe, but tnt should still work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, removing the "survives explosion" check on the second part allows it to drop, and it now works as intended